# Populate pandas dataframe after index values

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a DataFrame that looks like the one on the left below and I need to re-arrange so it looks like the one on the right:

```
  XYZ  year  month  values                     A      B      C      D
0   A  2006      8   35601            2005-01  NaN    NaN    NaN    NaN
1   A  2005      3   13164            2005-02  36889  NaN    NaN    NaN
2   A  2006      5   45830            2005-03  13164  NaN    NaN    NaN
3   A  2005      5   47495            2005-04  NaN    NaN    NaN    NaN
4   A  2005      2   36889     ->     .        
5   B  2006      1   33694            2006-01  NaN    33694  NaN    NaN
6   C  2006      2    7400            2006-02  NaN    NaN    7400   NaN
7   C  2006      6    5698            .
8   D  2006      6   14049            .
9   A  2005      9   22650            2006-08  35601  NaN    NaN    NaN
```

I have created the values that will be used as columns in the new DF, something like:

```
df1 = pd.DataFrame(..., columns=df.XYZ.unique().tolist())
```

and I have created the values that will be used as index in the new DF, something like:

```
df1 = pd.DataFrame(..., index=pd.date_range('2005-01-01', periods=24,freq='M').to_period('m'))
```

I need help to understand how to iterate through df so that I can use the matching value for each column, based that the new index is mapped correctly to legacy DF values for `['year','month']`

Any help is appreciated, thanks!

Comment: pivot your dataframe with year+month as index, then reindex on your date_range (make sure to use the same types)

Comment: Actually, it's easier to understand if I provide an example, see below

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use a [`pivot`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.pivot.html) and [`reindex`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.reindex.html) your values with the [`date_range`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.date_range.html):

```
(df.assign(date=pd.to_datetime(df[['year', 'month']].assign(day=1)
                               ).dt.to_period('m'))
   .pivot(index='date', columns='XYZ', values='values')
   .reindex(pd.date_range('2005-01-01', periods=24, freq='M').to_period('m'))
)
```

Output:

```
XYZ            A        B       C        D
2005-01      NaN      NaN     NaN      NaN
2005-02  36889.0      NaN     NaN      NaN
2005-03  13164.0      NaN     NaN      NaN
2005-04      NaN      NaN     NaN      NaN
2005-05  47495.0      NaN     NaN      NaN
2005-06      NaN      NaN     NaN      NaN
2005-07      NaN      NaN     NaN      NaN
2005-08      NaN      NaN     NaN      NaN
2005-09  22650.0      NaN     NaN      NaN
2005-10      NaN      NaN     NaN      NaN
2005-11      NaN      NaN     NaN      NaN
2005-12      NaN      NaN     NaN      NaN
2006-01      NaN  33694.0     NaN      NaN
2006-02      NaN      NaN  7400.0      NaN
2006-03      NaN      NaN     NaN      NaN
2006-04      NaN      NaN     NaN      NaN
2006-05  45830.0      NaN     NaN      NaN
2006-06      NaN      NaN  5698.0  14049.0
2006-07      NaN      NaN     NaN      NaN
2006-08  35601.0      NaN     NaN      NaN
2006-09      NaN      NaN     NaN      NaN
2006-10      NaN      NaN     NaN      NaN
2006-11      NaN      NaN     NaN      NaN
2006-12      NaN      NaN     NaN      NaN
```